# how take margin-left in input check box

Tags: html, css

Suppose to have:

```
<div class="home">
<input type="checkbox"/>....
</div>
```

I need to insert `margin-left:3px` to checkbox. My css code is:

```
.home+input[type=checkbox]{
margin-left:3px;
}
```

Anyone can help me^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.home input[type="checkbox"]{
margin-left:3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="home">
<input type="checkbox"/>....
</div>
```

You don't need the plus really... unless you have a specific need, and you need quotes around `checkbox`..!

Comment: you do not need quotes around attribute selectors. Unless you're using special characters, that's just a matter of taste.

Comment: Ahh I did not know that! Always done it out of force of habit!

Answer (score 2):

You almost had it, you just need to wrap checkbox inside quotes  `input[type="checkbox"]`

```css
input[type="checkbox"] 
  {
    margin-left:10px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="home">
<input type="checkbox"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Both of the other answers work, but neither of them is accurate.

Although I tend to recommend putting quotes around attribute selectors `[type="checkbox"]`, it will [work perfectly fine](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/unquoted-attribute-values) without quotes `[type=checkbox]`. Quotes are only necessary if you're including special characters.

The reason your code wasn't working was that the `+` in your selector [matches siblings](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

`.home+input[type=checkbox]{}` would match an input element with the type of checkbox that is placed immediately after an element with a class of home.

```
<div class="home">....</div>
<input type="checkbox"/>....
```

Since your input element is nested inside `.home`, you won't use the sibling selector `+`

That's why this code will do the trick:

```css
.home input[type=checkbox]{
margin-left:3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="home">
<input type="checkbox"/>....
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't know that! Will save me some time in the future!